# How to create ramfs on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, tmpfs

I have 24 GB RAM and a 8 GB swapfile. I know that under Arch Linux there's `/dev/shm` that uses `tmpfs` but I want to create a `ramfs` mount point because I want a place where I can temporary store sensitive files for work. It is very crucial that these files don't touch the disk in any shape or form.

I want to use ramfs instead of tmpfs because I know that tmpfs will use the swapfile if there isn't enough space left, which is something that I don't want.

My question is though, how do I create a ramfs mount point with at least 12G storage?

I tried `mount none ~/RAM -t ramfs -o size=12G` but it doesn't work. It does create the mount point but as soon as I try to drop files into it, it says `Need more than 3.1G space` to store files (I tried to copy a 5 GB iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The two main RAM based file system types in Linux are tmpfs and ramfs. ramfs is the older file system type and is largely replaced in most scenarios by tmpfs... tmpfs is a more recent RAM file system which overcomes many of the drawbacks with ramfs.

I don't think `ramfs` is relavent **today**, not with the current kernel.

> how do I create a ramfs mount point with at least 12G storage?

```
mkdir /ramdisk
# ramdisk is slang here, reads better than tmpfsdisk.

# my server has 512gb ram, so

mount -t tmpfs -o size=500G tmpfs /ramdisk

# in your case with 24gb ram I would do

mkdir /whatever
mount -t tmpfs -o size=22G tmpfs /whatever
```

The size is dynamic, in that you will have folder `/whatever` and it will eat zero memory until you start throwing stuff in there, but will fail once `size` is reached.  You can make `size` greater the amount of physical ram, you can make size (which is really *max size*) any number, if it's greater than physical RAM then that simply opens the risk of locking up the operating system when all memory is used up.

simply observe your `/whatever_ramdisk` via `df -h` showing `Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`.

If you don't want stuff to touch *disk*, then do not use a swap partition mounted from the disk.  Either don't create a swap partition on the disk in the first place, or in your case lose 8gb of disk and don't mount the swap partition remove it or comment out in `/etc/fstab`.  Or reformat that partition as `ext4` or `xfs` and mount it as `/data`.

*kernel swapping out pages* does not [always] mean writing data to the swap partition on disk.

I have not used a swap partition on disk in the last 10+ years... ready to reignite the swap wars... if I have a server with 768gb of ram and I use 1 300gb disk tell me how a swap partition on disk is of any value.  Better yet, diskless cluster nodes that PXE boot and rhel 8 runs completely in RAM on a node (server) having zero disks.  And if you think there's a security risk with `tmpfs`, well it's all file [permission] based just like the rest of linux. - if `/ramdisk` is a problem you say then so must be `/etc` and `/usr` and every other folder mounted or not as well as every other bit in your 24gb of memory.

Answer (score 0):

ramfs isn't any better or worse than tmpfs in terms of data not touching disk.

While it *is* true that ramfs doesn't support being swapped, the situation in which tmpfs files would get written to swap are the same in which pages of the applications handling the sensitive data would get written to swap.

So, your overall security benefit of using ramfs instead of tmpfs is zero, if not even negative! It's often relatively easy to force an application to generate much temporary files – with ramfs, that forces the kernel to start swapping out pages from process spaces, including those with confidential data that's not been written to a temporary file. Suddenly, trying to do the secure thing makes your system more vulnerable.

Because: If you used tmpfs and *encrypted* your swap, then neither the swapping of tmpfs content nor of application data would lead to security problems.

Also: I'd be interested in your threat model, in which you can trust your machine, but your swap storage device is untrustworthy. If you can't trust your storage, I hope you have at least measured boot, because then you also can't trust that the operating system you're booting is not simply sending your confidential data to a person willing selling it back to you for a nominal fee. If you *have* measured boot, and just can't trust your swap device (interesting combination! The file systems containing code are immutable at run time to an attacker, but your swap isn't?), then you've still lost, because an attacker could obviously just modify what is in swap, including code, scripts and configuration files, quickly taking over your processes.

So, from my perspective, encrypted swap is the only safe swap that you'd have under these threat models, and it would also allow you to use tmpfs. So, encrypt your swap, use tmpfs, be happy :)

Comment: My thread model is that of an activist/journalist. My swapfile lies on my system drive. My system drive is fully encrypted. It's not about trusting my device/swap, rather making sure that I do everything correctly so that I can sleep well at night knowing no accidents happened that lead to a leak to disk. Even if said leak would still leave my data encrypted.

Comment: but in that case, as explained above, ramfs potentially increases the confidential data "leaked" to disk (it's not really leaked if it's properly encrypted), instead of decreasing it, by "pressing out" application data to swap, which is potentially even more sensitive information. So, don't use ramfs, but tmpfs, as ramfs has no advantages.

Comment: I see. I will be using tmpfs then. Thank you for your insight!